# React, render dinamic child passing prop

Tags: reactjs

I'm slowly getting introduced into advanced React and best practices for production apps. I want to know what is considered the "best practice" way of rendering a dinamic child passing props regarding maintainability, readability etc:

Here is the [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fast-ngk4zq) for more details

First method, render children as function passing the prop:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./Mouses.css"

export default function MouseChildren ({children}) {

    const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState(undefined)

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        setMousePos({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})
    }
/* this is bad because if more than one child is passed it will break */
    return (
        <div className="Mouse-container" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
            {children(mousePos)}
        </div>
    )    
}
```

and then you call it this way:

```
<MouseChildren>
   {position => <RandomDiv position={position} method="children as function method" />}
</MouseChildren>
```

Second method, render function as prop:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./Mouses.css"

export default function MouseRenderMethod ({render}) {

    const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState(undefined)

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        setMousePos({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})
    }

    return (
        <div className="Mouse-container" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
            {render(mousePos)}
        </div>
    )    
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
<MouseRenderMethod render={position => <RandomDiv position={position} method="render as prop method:" />} />
```

and the third method is using React.Children:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./Mouses.css"

export default function MouseCreateComponent({children}) {

    const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState(undefined)

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        setMousePos({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})
    }

    return (
        <div className="Mouse-container" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
            {React.Children.map(React.Children.toArray(children), child => {
                if (React.isValidElement(child)) return React.cloneElement(child, {position: mousePos}, null)
            })}
        </div>
    )    
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
<MouseCreateComponent>
    <RandomDiv method="React.CloneElement method" />
</MouseCreateComponent>
```

I'm not sure which way is considered to be best over the others. If you from your experience can explain a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass anything in your code without retyping it, you need to use `useContext` and the structure is:

One example with full-functionality which it may help you is:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [userData, setUserData]=useState('nothing here')

// any code you want to pass in the code
//e.g. a function
const randomFunction = ()=>{
//do something here
}

 return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
       userData,
       setUserData,
       randomFunction
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

then all you have to do is to wrap all the components (children) you want, e.g. wrap `<App />` so, more or less everything:

```
 <AppProvider>
      <App />
 </AppProvider>
```

So now in this case you can use everything from your `AppContext` in all your code, you can pass more variables and functions if you want, and you import that by using:

```
import { useGlobalContext } from '/pathYouHaveIt';

function App() {
  const {
       userData,
       setUserData,
       randomFunction,
  } = useGlobalContext();

// now you can use those like you have them set-up in the App()
```